# How to call function on post back

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have made function to add class on a div which is working fine. But when another function call postback then my added class is removed from the div because it reload the page. So I want to call my function on postback or after postpack. example function is given below

```
<head>
<style>
.test{ background:#F00}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
$(this).addClass('test')
})
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">click</a>
<div>check....</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using updatepanels? anywhere? i mean ASP.net?

Comment: yes. Here is example code  __doPostBack('<%=hfRefreshUpdatePanelview1.ClientID %>','add'+';'+addvalue+';'+index);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this one

you have to write this code 2 times. Means once you have defined in your script and other is this one

because

*The **PageRequestManager** class exposes methods, properties, and events to make client programming easier when page elements are performing asynchronous postbacks. For example, the PageRequestManager class enables you to handle events in the client page life cycle and to provide custom event handlers that are specific to partial-page updates.*

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest($(function(){
                      $('a').click(function(){
                        $('div').addClass('test')
                      })
                  }));
```

This will surely work

Comment: Thanks Dhaval, I will try this and come back to you. Thanks a lot for answering

Comment: One more thing. I am using this keywork of javascript. is this work on code behind

Comment: No, you need to do this stuff in purely `javascript`

Comment: But is this code var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance() will work on javascript file

Comment: you have to give this inline in every page where postback occures. In `.aspx` too